# ASIHTTPRequest cansel request (using block)

Tags: ios, asihttprequest

I need to cancel my request. How can I make this. I have tried to create property and use it as assign for `ASIHTTPRequest *request`. But when I called `[request cancel]` I have bed access, because request retain count has 0 (due `[ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url]` return autorelease object). I can't create strong property, I get this warning:

```
Capturing 'request' strongly in this block is likely to lead to a retain cycle
```

This is my code below:

```
__unsafe_unretained __block ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setCompletionBlock:^{       
    NSString *response = [request responseString];  
}];
[request setFailedBlock:^{          
}];
[request startAsynchronous];
```

Comment: Are you setting `request` to nil at completion/failure blocks ?

Comment: no, i don't do it. this is just what I call in method1 and in the method2 I call [request cancel].

Comment: it might be that you are canceling the request before it starts or after it's finished, you'll want to set the reference to `nil` at the completion blocks as they will release the request object

Comment: i try to use somewere if (self.request) than and only than it should invoke cancel for request. But when I check self.request I get bad access (NSZombie) retain count -1 for this object, because method [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url] return autorelease object.

Comment: self.request this is assign property.

Comment: you are responsible for setting the `request` reference to nil, the object gets deallocated doesn't mean each of it's reference will be automatically set to nil. It means `self.deallocatedvar` will not help you avoid the messages to deallocated vars. Autoreleased request property must be fine as the blocks retain the variable and release it at completion, if you also set the reference to nil it must be safe to call `[requesr cancel]` even after it's deallocated. Normally this call should not happen from design though.